# How can I use the solve function to solve vectors instead of scalar

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrices equations, and I need to solve the equation to get the value of such vectors, when I use the function solve, it gives me the error as below:
Error using sym.getEqnsVars>checkVariables (line 92)
Second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables.

```
Error in sym.getEqnsVars (line 56)
    checkVariables(vars);

Error in sym/solve>getEqns (line 429)
[eqns, vars] = sym.getEqnsVars(argv{:});

Error in sym/solve (line 226)
[eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});
```

This is the code I am using:

```
clear all; clc; 
w2 = rand(2,2); 
w3 = rand(2,2); 
F2 = rand(2,2); 

w5 = rand(2,2); 
w6 = rand(2,2); 
F5 = rand(2,2);

w8 = rand(2,2); 
w9 = rand(2,2); 
F8 = rand(2,2);

y1 = rand(2,1); 
y2 = rand(2,1); 
y3 = rand(2,1);

syms x2 x3 s2 
solve(-w2*x2 - w3*x3 + F2*s2 == y1, -w5*x2 - w6*x3 + F5*s2 == y2, -w8*x2 - w9*x3 + F8*s2 == y3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a syntax error. The solve function takes (can take) symbolic parameters (the ones you're trying to solve for) as arguments. Since you separated your equations with commas, Matlab understood this as secondary arguments to the function solve. You need to use matrix brackets, check the revised form below:

```
sol = solve([-w2*x2 - w3*x3 + F2*s2 == y1, -w5*x2 - w6*x3 + F5*s2 == y2, -w8*x2 - w9*x3 + F8*s2 == y3], [x2, x3, s2]);
```

This code runs, but the function is not able to find a solution for these sets of parameters. Meaning, sol returns a struct with 3 empty members.

Comment: but I think that function can not solve the x2 , x2 and s2 as they are vector, not scalar ! Second, the matrices are generated randomly, It's not logic that all sol are 3 empty members in all cases.

Comment: The way you wrote you function is incorrect; I have given you the correct form. If a solution cannot be found, the function returns nothing, hence the empty matrices "[]". There really is not much else to discuss further here.